# EF Core 7.0 - OwnsOne throws NRE internally

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

Using EntityFrameworkCore v7.0.0 (with SQL Server adapter)

I am attempting to attach an owned entity to a principal entity by invoking `.OwnsOne(...)`, however EFCore is generating a `NullReferenceException` internally while attempting to generate a shadowed foreign key.

The code is as following:

```cs
public class ProductId : ValueObject
{
    public Guid Value { get; private set; }

    private ProductId(Guid value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static ProductId Create(Guid value)
    {
        return new ProductId(value);
    }
}

public class ProductName : ValueObject 
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public ProductName(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    // ValueObject overrides
}

public abstract class AggregateRoot<TId> where TId : notnull
{
    // ... ctor
}

public class Product : AggregateRoot<ProductId>
{
    private Product() { }

    public ProductName Name { get; private set; }
}
```

And the following implementation of `IEntityTypeConfiguration<>`:

```cs
public class ProductConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Products");

        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);

        builder.Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasConversion(
                id => id.Value,
                value => ProductId.Create(value));

        builder.OwnsOne(
            p => p.Name,
            navBuilder =>
            {
                navBuilder.Property(x => x.Value)
                    .HasColumnName(nameof(Product.Name))
                    .IsRequired();
            });
    }
}
```

EFCore stack trace of the NRE that occurrs:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.CreateForeignKey(InternalEntityTypeBuilder principalEntityTypeBuilder, IReadOnlyList`1 dependentProperties, Key principalKey, String propertyBaseName, Nullable`1 required, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.HasRelationship(EntityType targetEntityType, Nullable`1 navigationToTarget, Nullable`1 inverseNavigation, Nullable`1 setTargetAsPrincipal, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Nullable`1 required)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.HasOwnership(EntityType targetEntityType, MemberIdentity& navigation, Nullable`1 inverse, ConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalEntityTypeBuilder.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.IConventionEntityTypeBuilder.HasOwnership(IConventionEntityType targetEntityType, MemberInfo navigation, Boolean fromDataAnnotation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.RelationshipDiscoveryConvention.CreateRelationships(IEnumerable`1 relationshipCandidates, IConventionEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.RelationshipDiscoveryConvention.Process(IConventionEntityType entityType, String navigationName, MemberInfo memberInfo, IConventionContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.RelationshipDiscoveryConvention.ProcessNavigationRemoved(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder sourceEntityTypeBuilder, IConventionEntityTypeBuilder targetEntityTypeBuilder, String navigationName, MemberInfo memberInfo, IConventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnNavigationRemoved(IConventionEntityTypeBuilder sourceEntityTypeBuilder, IConventionEntityTypeBuilder targetEntityTypeBuilder, String navigationName, MemberInfo memberInfo)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnNavigationRemovedNode.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.DelayedConventionScope.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.OwnsOneBuilder[TRelatedEntity](TypeIdentity ownedType, MemberIdentity navigation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.OwnsOne[TRelatedEntity](Expression`1 navigationExpression, Action`1 buildAction)
   at CustomNamespace.Persistence.ProductConfiguration.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder`1 builder) in C:\CustomNamespace\Persistence\ProductConfiguration.cs:line 27
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration[TEntity](IEntityTypeConfiguration`1 configuration)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, Func`2 predicate)
   at CustomNamespace.Persistence.DbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) in C:\CustomNamespace\Persistence\DbContext.cs:line 16
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_4(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

I tried researching and debugging through the EFCore OwnsOne implementation, however I did not manage to find the cause. I have other entities that follow the same logic and everything works as expected.

Comment: EF Core 7 itself doesn't throw in `OwnsOne`. Your code shows an attempt to use DDD concepts in the ORM though. DDD refers to domain objects, not ORMs. Entities aren't aggregate roots and primary key types aren't DDD value objects. In a specific use case, eg an eCommerce application, or order application, the aggregate root is the object that combines all the orders, order items, customers, products, prices etc used in that specific use case. That may be a `Cart`. Using an ORM eliminates 95% of the code needed to construct this, but doesn't make the ORM entity a DDD root

Comment: Instead of using concepts that may not be needed *at all* in your application, try using EF Core by itself *first*. Right now you're leaking ORM concepts to the business layer (because you load the ORM entities) and business concepts down to the ORM.

Comment: I wanted to provide some for the code, it is not important that DDD principles are applied on the domain layer. What is important is that `OwnsOne` throws a NullReferenceException while trying to attach `ProductName` owned entity to the principal entity - `Product`.

Comment: If such a basic feature wasn't working, none of the examples would work and all developers using EF Core would have noticed. `ProductName` isn't an entity, it's a property. You're still trying to make the ORM work like DDD, using the wrong terms and functions for the wrong thing. *Remove* all attempts to use DDD terms like the `ValueObject` and `AggregateRoot` classes, use plain old C# objects and check whether `OwnsOne` works or not - assuming it makes sense. Only then try to make things fancier

Comment: I should be able to persist a `ProductName` ValueObject as an owned type - ie map the `Product.ProductName.Value` to an SQL table [Products] - [Name] column. I don't see why it's important how my domain layer is structured. I am not saying that the basic feature of EFCore is not working - only that it's not working for me in this particular case, although I have other entities implementing the same principles and it's working as one would expect.

Comment: There's no "domain" in C#, only types and properties. The type and property names are mixed up because the actual properties you want to map aren't what the configuration says they are. The error isn't thrown by `OwnsOne`, it's thrown when EF Core tries to find the relations between those types. The config says there's a navigation relation between `ProductName` and `Product`. Relations have keys, but `ProductName` has no keys, so  `CreateRelationships` fails.

Comment: Test-driven development is a key concept of DDD, and right now this is the opposite. Instead of trying to get working code and modify it, the question starts from the end, with failing, complex code. Start with a simple DbContext and entities that don't inherit anything. Make sure it compiles and passes the unit tests. For this you can use the in-memory EF Core provider instead of a database. Once that works, add a base class where really needed. Get the tests to pass. Then try to use custom types instead of simple values.

Answer (score 1):

Took 19 days to figure this out. I'm could be wrong. In my case, I was trying to define a User with many Roles and getting the same error. Then today, after changing User to FarmUser and Role to FarmRole solved the issue. There's a possibility the reflection first tries to resolve something predefined.

Comment: This is a possibility. I have tried reproducing this issue in freshly created solutions and I am unable to reproduce it with the same configuration. Really don't understand what causes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found related issues on EF GitHub and managed to reproduce the issue myself. The issue occurrs when a CLR type is defined as a property on entity X and as a single (or collection of) owned entity on entity Y.
For Example:

```cs
public class FooId 
{
    public Guid Value { get; private set; }
}

public class BarId 
{
    public Guid Value { get; private set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    private Foo()
    {
    }
    
    public FooId Id { get; private set; }

    public FooDetail Detail { get; private set; }
}

public class FooDetail 
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    private FooDetail()
    {
    }
}

public class Bar
{
    private readonly List<FooId> _fooIds = new();

    private Bar()
    {
    }

    public BarId Id { get; private set; }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<FooId> FooIds => _fooIds.AsReadOnly();
}


public class FooConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Foo> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Foos");

        builder.HasKey(f => f.Id);
        
        builder.Property(f => f.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasConversion(
                id => id.Value,
                value => FooId.Create(value));

        // This line will throw NRE because:
        // FooId is used as a property on Foo
        // And FooId is used as a collection of owned entities on Bar
        builder.OwnsOne(
            f => f.Detail,
            dBuilder => 
            {
                dBuilder.Property(d => d.Value)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("Detail")
                    .HasMaxLength(100);
            });
    }
}

public class BarConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Bar>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Bar> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Bars");

        builder.HasKey(f => f.Id);
        
        builder.Property(f => f.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasConversion(
                id => id.Value,
                value => FooId.Create(value));

        builder.OwnsMany(
            b => b.FooIds,
            fBuilder => 
            {
                fBuilder.ToTable("BarFooIds");

                fBuilder.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("BarId");

                fBuilder.HasKey("Id");

                fBuilder.Property(f => f.Value)
                    .ValueGeneratedNever()
                    .HasColumnName(nameof(FooId));
            });

        builder.MetaData
            .FindNavigation(nameof(Bar.FooIds))!
            .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}
```

Related GitHub issues:

[EF issue 30203](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30203)

[EF issue 30373](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/30373)